# darkflow bounding boxes bad even in standard example

Tags: image, box, bounding, darkflow

The neural network on Darkflow is not training correctly.

At first I thought I did not have enough images, or maybe a bad starting network. So I tried a standard example such as 
https://github.com/deep-diver/Soccer-Ball-Detection-YOLOv2/blob/master/YOLOv2-Train.ipynb
but even then I had the exact same issue (see error image).

I can test with a pre-trained network just fine. It is only when I try to train on a network that I get nonsense. Yet at the end of 100 epochs I have:

step 1100 - loss 1.004814863204956 - moving ave loss 1.1848642304486146
Finish 100 epoch(es)

I am training with:

```
flow --model cfg/yolo_custom.cfg    \
     --load bin/yolo.weights         \
     --train                          \
     --annotation labelImg/annotations \
     --dataset labelImg/images          \
     --epoch 100                         \
     --gpu 1.0
```

and testing with:

```
flow --model cfg/yolo_custom.cfg \
     --load bin/yolo.weights      \
     --demo test_video.mp4         \
     --saveVideo
```

(which one can find at that website)

He shows the images he gets on that website. I instead get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/chQGV.jpg

Comment: Tried it on a different dataset (200+) racoons. It can't even find the racoon within it's own training set:
https://imgur.com/a/83bcGeT

Could there be something wrong with my setup? I am on Ubuntu, using a gtx 1060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There were 2 things:
1. I needed to tell it to load a particular checkpoint of that configuration with "**`--load 21000`**" (or whatever number was most recent)
2. I needed to overfit it on 3-5 images first, then let it train on the rest of the images.